# Configure Glassfish 3 with Hibernate 3.6

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, hibernate-search

I am trying to configure hibernate 3.6.7 with glassfish 3.1.1.
If I just install the module from update-tool in glassfish I get hibernate 3.5...

I want to use hibernate search 3.4.1 Final.

I want to build a website and I will have lots of items into database and I want it work ok (use lucene search integrated in hibernate). - I want to use lucene spellchecker later

Do you suggest me to switch to jboss AS 7? I am willing to create a java ee application (ejb, standalone web tier) if so... do I have to create more xml's, configuration stuff for jboss as 7? or just add my datasource and I'm done...???

Or should I make my lucene code and use it with eclipselink?

What do you think it's best?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Eclipse and glassfish 3.1 with Hibernate 3.6.7. and hibernate search. Everything works fine. You don't need tons of xml, I use JPA so I have persistence.xml. I set my database access in glassfish, put the jta datasource into the persistence.xml and some hibernate search related config, that's all.

I tried jboss too, but I think glassfish is easier to use. I don't know what's the best, pick one and try it :)

Comment: Where and how did you put hibernate jars? I tried to do this but it's not working for me..

Comment: I made an user library in eclipse, and put all the necessary jars by manually. (hibernate jar, necessary and required additional jars in hibernate lib and jdbc connector). Then add this library to the eclipse project build path.

Comment: but how did you added the libraries in glassfish? because I read something about osgi and stuff that you have to do in glassfish in order to recognize the jars... or you did an ant or something that is deploying your application and you didn't use the eclipse deployment server stuff?

Comment: I use the eclipse deployment stuff, just add a new server, develop your application then deploy with eclipse. You don't have to add hibernate library to glassfish, eclipse take care. Only thing you have to do: set the database connection in glassfish admin panel (or set in the persistence.xml) and add the jdbc connector to glassfish lib directory.

Comment: I did the same thing but it's not working.. I get.. class not found exception org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence... I added a new user library and added all hibernate jars and then checked them into "order and export" under my ejb project properties... p.s: I added the mysql connector into my glassfish lib folder...

Comment: Here is a very good tutorial it contains eclipse + glassfish configuration. Hope it helps: [link](http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/)

Comment: well.. I didn't have enough time to investigate but seems like a pretty good solution but still... dirty... I will stick with eclipselink and do by myself some anotations and I will use java ee AOP to perform the indexing.. I prefer querying by myself... thank you anyway... Finally I got an error that can not find javax.persistence.Entity or something.. and this is why I abandoned..

Comment: Not at all. Another advice: check imports of the annotations, one annotation can be in some different jar. So maybe eclipse imported other jar than you expect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4022/discussion-between-alex-and-hcpeter)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @hcpeter I managed to configure...

Here is how is done:

Copy all jar files (only jar files, no folders.. take the jars out of the folders) in glassfish3/glassfish/lib/